# Prevent or rollback the postback on page_load

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, postback

First of all, I can't use Async plugins like Jquery, Ajax, UpdatePanel, etc.

I have an ASP.NET 4 WEBFORM, In the master page I verify if the Session is lost, in that case a show a modal to get the username/password and log-in the user again.

But I've two problems, the first one is that for example if I press a button and I lost the session, the webpage show me the modal but the code behind of the clickevent still execute it and i want to prevent it (I dont want to verify the state of the session in every event handler of the APP).

The second one is that after Im success on log-in the user, i want to finish or continue the event that the user tries before he lost the session.

I other words my problem is that I need to prevent the postback in the middle of it, and then do it again. :/

Something like this:

```
Page_Load(...)
{
If(Session["User"] == null)
{
  PostBack.Cancel(); //Like de e.PreventDefault() of Javascript.
  return;
}
.
.
}

AND

LoginOnSessionLost()
{
...
//After Login Success
Postback.Continue();
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPITALS in your title. Also, don't include tags (such as `C#`) in your titles -- that's what tags are for.

Comment: you can add code in your Global.asax file also where or what is triggering your postback..? google how to use the __doPostBack

Comment: if a PostBack has been triggered, then you need to have code that would check if(IsPostBack) && (IsNullOrEmpty(Session["User"])){} try something like that.. then do a redirect to the login page.. you could also check if(Page.IsValid) you should cleanup that code example to real working code..

Comment: @DJKRAZE thanks, i actually trying to implement the Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute on Global.asax, but i still need a way to tell it to stop the event and dont change the webform

Comment: Take a look at this link it should provide a working example to get you started http://www.techrepublic.com/article/working-with-the-aspnet-globalasax-file/5771721

Comment: If you are checking your session on master page then you should know first about the load event of master page and content page. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552097/in-what-order-asp-net-master-pages-execute

Comment: thanks i already know that the page_load of the content load first than the page_load of the masterpage, that is why i check the session state on the content page_load too, all i need is a command to stop the postback or something similar