# Why is my session variable declared in master page blank on a web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, session-variables

I declared in master page load:

```
Session["sessionString"] = "stringX";
```

in my web page on load also, i call it

```
string sessionString= (string)Session["sessionString"];
```

i debug and value in web page is "" what is wrong?

Comment: store that value as a get{} set{} property in master page and access accordingly in the child pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JW Lim is correct...content page's load event will fire before Master page load.

@user3445314 , you can use "Session_Start" event in Global.asax and set values same as you set in master page.

"Session_Start" event fires first and then your content page load event occur.

I hope this may be solve your problem

Comment: Thanks! Understood. I'll work my around it with that in mind.

Comment: @user3445314 I would suggest *against* using the `Session_Start` event in Global.asax. You will be setting the value *each time a new session starts*. Use the `Init` or `PreLoad` events on your master page. Unless you plan on using the value of `sessionString` on many webpages, which in that case you should declare it as a public constant in your master page or another `GlobalValues` class instead of storing it in session.

Answer (score 3):

The `Page_Load` event of a content page is called *before* the `Page_Load` event of the master page (see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4552116/3155705) and [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX)). Hence, when you call

```
string sessionString= (string)Session["sessionString"];
```

in your web page, `Session["sessionString"]` does not contain any value yet and defaults to an empty string.

As a workaround, you could set the value of `Session["sessionString"]` on the `Init` or `PreLoad` events of your master page.

Comment: i think the master page is always called first i believe. Anyway in my case, yes master page is first. i put breakpoints in both and master page is first, then check content page, shows "" on sessionString variable :(

Comment: @user3445314 No, the content page's `Load` event is always called first. Here's the [official MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) : "6. Content page Load event. 
7. Master page Load event"

Answer (score 0):

Declare Session in Master PreRender

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
   Session["sessionString"] = "stringX";
}
```

And get it by ContetPage OnUnload event

```
protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)
{
   string sessionString= (string)Session["sessionString"];
}
```